# How to correctly select categories and tags for blog post?

Tags: oop, concurrency, blogs

When I was writing a blog recently, I learned about the concepts of category and tag. As I have been reviewing the knowledge of OOP recently, I found that category is the relation of is-a and tag is the relation of has-a.

Now my question is that I am writing an article on C++ concurrency, and now that I have the category in the C++ learning manual, I am wondering whether to create a new category for concurrent programming, where there are two categories, or a new tag, where there is only one category

Comment: Your question doesn't follow the community [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are asking a question about how to organize articles on a blog. This should be used for asking question about programming.

Try going to the [writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com) stack exchange site and posting this question there.

Comment: Nice blog though, I love the site design!

Comment: Thank you, but I think it's a lot like object-oriented programming, where categories are like inheritance and tags are like member classes

Comment: You're correct they're definitely similar